# How to extract the value of the attribute picture using Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I have been looking for an XPath code to get the value of the attribute of an HTML element as part of my testing.

```
<div class="gallery-list">
<figure class="figure hd" ng-class="profileGallery.css" profile-item-remove="9>
    <a href="https://#" data-login="" gallery-modal="9" rel="nofollow">
    <picture sl-video-preview="https://movie.mp4" sl-safe="" class="ng-isolate-scope sl-safe">
    </a>
</figure>
<div>
```

I need get value of attribue by xpath  **sl-video-preview**
Some can help us.
thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the value of the *attribue* `sl-video-preview`, as the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.gallery-list > figure.figure.hd > a > picture.ng-isolate-scope.sl-safe"))).get_attribute("sl-video-preview"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='gallery-list']/figure[@class='figure hd']/a/picture[@class='ng-isolate-scope sl-safe']"))).get_attribute("sl-video-preview"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: perfect your example, works fine for that i need.. thanks a lot /o/

Comment: in some cases, the atribute picture are displayed a lot of times in div gallery-list.. i need get all figure an put it inside a loop to get one by one

Comment: @dmrpy Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please? StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: put new question bellow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the generic xpath that you can use.

```
//figure[@class='figure hd']/picture
```

And you have to get 'sl-video-preview' attribute.

**Chrome Console Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have problem, why in some cases the tag figure appear multiple times and this example by @DebanjanB get only one record, then I need all results.

```
<div class="gallery-list">
<figure class="figure" ng-class="profileGallery.css" profile-item-remove="9>
    <a href="https://#" data-login="" gallery-modal="9" rel="nofollow">
    <picture sl-video-preview="https://movie.mp4" sl-safe="" class="ng-isolate-scope sl-safe">
    </a>
</figure>
<figure class="figure hd" ng-class="profileGallery.css" profile-item-remove="9>
    <a href="https://#" data-login="" gallery-modal="9" rel="nofollow">
    <picture sl-video-preview="https://movie.mp4" sl-safe="" class="ng-isolate-scope sl-safe">
    </a>
</figure>
<figure class="figure" ng-class="profileGallery.css" profile-item-remove="9>
    <a href="https://#" data-login="" gallery-modal="9" rel="nofollow">
    <picture sl-video-preview="https://movie.mp4" sl-safe="" class="ng-isolate-scope sl-safe">
    </a>
</figure>
<div>
```

XPath Example that works:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='gallery-list']/figure[@class='figure hd']/a/picture[@class='ng-isolate-scope sl-safe']"))).get_attribute("sl-video-preview"))
```

How do to get all records?